# Missing a temporary folder.error when image is uploaded in admin Set temporary Directory - Wordpress 5.2.2

Tags: images, directory, uploads

I am finding this error when I try to upload image in backend

> Missing a temporary folder.

Tried setting temporary folder in wp-config.php with necessary permissions. Tried to set the temporary directory path in global and local php.ini files. No fix yet.

When uploading image found the below errors

> 2019/08/31 05:16:52 [warn] 12906#12906: *853 a client request body is
>   buffered to a temporary file /var/cache/nginx/client_temp/0000000278,
>   client: , server: , request: "POST /wp-admin/media-new.php
>   HTTP/1.1", host: ".com", referrer:
>   "wp-admin/media-new.php"
>
> 2019/08/31 05:16:53 [error] 12906#12906: *853 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "PHP message: PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create
>   a temporary file in Unknown on line 0" while reading response
>   header from upstream, client: , request: "POST
>   /wp-admin/media-new.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host:
>   "", referrer:
>   "/wp-admin/media-new.php" "

Using Nginx Server in a VPS. I am struck here for the past 3 days, though I haven' t found any solution yet.

Kindly advise me over ths

Answer (score 1):

Restart PHP-FPM and it will resolve this issue :)

PS: I know its an old thread, but anyone came here for the same issue, do this to get it resolved

Answer (score 0):

To add to mahaidery's answer.

SSH into your root folder and run the following commands:

/scripts/restartsrv_cpanel_php_fpm

/scripts/restartsrv_apache_php_fpm

Ref: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/how-to-restart-php-fpm-using-ssh.596171/